# Can I force merge a Catalina "- Data" and system Volume?

Tags: disk-utility, apfs

We're all familiar with the "Macintosh HD" and "Macintosh HD - Data" layout.  I don't know what my customer did but he has both Volumes intact but the firmlinks are gone.  They are being treated as 2 entirely independent volumes.  The contents of the "Users" folder on the -Data volume is not being presented as the users on the Mac itself.  And if I create a new user, it puts that user's folder under Users on the "Macintosh HD" volume only, not copied to the "Macintosh HD - Data" volume.

Diskutils says that the "Macintosh HD" volume is in a Volume Group with a different volume other than the "Macintosh HD - Data" volume.

So I'd like to disassociate this 3rd volume and re-associate the "Macintosh HD" and "Macintosh HD - Data" regarding those firmlinks the way they belong.

Comment: Might be easier to backup what needs backup and then reinstall the system from scratch.

Comment: @nohillside Plan B will be to copy stuff to that 3rd Volume that seems to be associated.  Plan C is reinstall / restore.

Comment: Go with @nohillside’s suggestion.  The problem is within the APFS container, each has a UUID (of sorts - can’t remember the exact name right now) that links one to the other and then it creates another unique number to identify that.  If you happen to reconnect them, that number is now different and I can’t predict what would happen - it would make a great academic exercise, but not at the expense of getting the customer back to work.  You could be dealing with continuing issues related to this - just redo it and move forward.